# OpenCV c++ code for mexican hat operator

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

Can any one help me to find the **Open CV** `c++` code for Mexican hat operator. I need the code for detecting the license plate. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a LoG (Mexican Hat) -filtered image by decomposing the operation as:

```
Mat mhFiltered; // resulting (MHat-filtered image)
Mat gaussianBlurredImage;
GaussianBlur(image, gaussianBlurredImage,Size(5,5),1.5); // First apply the gaussian operator
Laplacian(gaussianBlurredImage,mhFiltered,CV_32F,3); // Then the Laplacian
```

Notice that the parameters of `GaussianBlur` and `Laplacian` will alter the final result. Read the OpenCV reference to learn how they work!

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to use [Difference of Gaussians (DoG) filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians) it is an approximation of Mexican Hat filter. 
And it's just a difference of two images blurred with different sigmas.